# Any suggestion for CV template with Pdflatex typesetting ?

Tags: templates, article, cv

I am creating a document with PDFlatex typesetting and article document class. 
I want my CV to be included in this document. 
Does anyone have any template which is modified for PDflatex and Article document class? ( Unfortunately, all CV template that i have seen is for Xelatex )

Thanks

Comment: You could use `pdfpages` package to append the article and the CV, maybe written with `moderncv` document class.

Comment: @astrinus unfortunately, I have header so i could not append my CV to this document

Comment: Many CV-templates use XeLaTeX to use fancy fonts. As your document should be consistent in all parts, you wouldn't want the fonts to be used anyway. Kick out all the `fontspec` related clutter and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following for resume templates:

```
http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae
```